# SVNClient.logMessages never returns a result

Tags: java, svn, javahl

I'm using JavaHL to connect to a 1.6 svn repos. While I managed to list the contents of the repository, I'm not able to get the item history (the comments made on the check ins as well as the dates and the authors).

As far as I see, SVNClient.logMessages is the right method, but the callback method is never been executed. I used Revision.HEAD for the path revision and a revision range object holding Revision.START and Revision.HEAD; the limit is set to 0 (which is no limit according to the documentation). I'm trying to fetch the revision, the date, the author and the comment.

If someone knows about example code on using JavaHL I'm maybe able to find my fault by comparing that code to mine.

BTW: I know about SVNKit, but the management decided not to buy it. Thus I have to use JavaHL, where next-to-no sample programs exist (and the doc will merely list the classes and interfaces without a very detailed description). So, please point me in that direction of SVNKit as this is impossible for me.

Any pointers appreciated.

Gnarf

Comment: The issue has been solved. The problem was the call to SVNClient.logMessages, especially the revision range used. The first revision had been described to be Revision.START. However, despite the description given for Revision.START, Revision.getInstance(1) finally made it work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved. The problem was the call to SVNClient.logMessages(), especially the revision range used.

The start revision had been Revision.START that, according to the documentation, is used to describe the "first existing revision".

The problem disappeared when I used Revision.getInstance(1) instead. As it is reasonable that any item has at least one revision (the initial one) with that number, it should be save to use that.

Hopefully this will save anyone else from spending another two-and-a-half days to figure it out!

Gnarf